# How do I check a specific value in a DataFrame is not unique, if not unique then I need to check the value of another cell in df then append True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to go through my df looking to see if the row starting with OBR and col3 is unique I have named this value Acc.

In this DataFrame I care about 2 variables Acc and MRN the Acc variable is always in the 3rd column and there is an OBR in the first column of the row containing the Acc variable. The MRN is similar it is in the 3rd column and there is always a PID in the first column of that row. The MRN can come in 2 forms A number followed by ^^^WANT (i.e. 28444302^^^WANT) or it can come as just the ^^^WANT with no number.

If Acc is unique and by unique I mean that in the DataFrame there is no other Acc with the same value. More specific is that there is no other value in column 3 with a row starting with OBR having the same value. If this is the case then I would append 'unique to the end of that row.

If there is an Acc that is the same as another Acc in different row then I need to check the MRN for that section (the sections are broke up by the /n rows) if all of the MRNs in each of the sections with the same Acc come back in the form a number followed by ^^^WANT (i.e. 60003212^^^WANT) then you can skip them.

if there is an Acc that is the same aalue as another Acc in a different row and one or more of the MRNs are just the value ^^^WANT then I want to append 'Not Unique' to the end of the rows with the same Acc value.

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   col1  col2         col3  col4   col5   col6  col7  col8
0   MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
1   PID     b  MRN1^^^WANT     d      s  PickB     b     b
2   OBR     e         Acc1        PickD      v     e     e
3   OBX     g            h     e             s           g
4   ORC     i            j     p      p      p     i     i
5    /n  none         nine  none   none   none  none  none
6   MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
7   PID     c      ^^^WANT     d      s  PickF     c     c
8   OBX     g            h     e      z      s     g     g
9   ORC     i            j            p      p     i     i
10  OBR     e         Acc2        PickG      v           e
11  OBX     g            h     e             s     g     g
12  OBX     i            j     p      p      p     i     i
13  OBX     g            h     e             s     g      
14  OBX     i            j     p      p      p     i     i
15   \n  none         none  none   none   none  none  none
16  MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
17  PID     c  MRN3^^^WANT     d      s  PickH     c     c
18  OBX     g            h     e      z      s     g     g
19  ORC     i            j            p      p     i     i
20  OBR     e         Acc3        PickJ      v     e     e
21   \n  none         none  none   none   none  none  none
22  MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
23  PID     c      ^^^WANT     d      s  PickK     c     c
24  OBR     e         Acc1        PickM      v     e     e
25  OBX     g            h     e             s     g
```

Expected output would look like this:

```
   col1  col2         col3  col4   col5   col6  col7  col8  col9
0   MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
1   PID     b  MRN1^^^WANT     d      s  PickB     b     b
2   OBR     e         Acc1        PickD      v     e     e  Not Unique
3   OBX     g            h     e             s           g
4   ORC     i            j     p      p      p     i     i
5    /n  none         nine  none   none   none  none  none
6   MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
7   PID     c      ^^^WANT     d      s  PickF     c     c
8   OBX     g            h     e      z      s     g     g
9   ORC     i            j            p      p     i     i
10  OBR     e         Acc2        PickG      v           e  unique
11  OBX     g            h     e             s     g     g
12  OBX     i            j     p      p      p     i     i
13  OBX     g            h     e             s     g      
14  OBX     i            j     p      p      p     i     i
15   \n  none         none  none   none   none  none  none
16  MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
17  PID     c  MRN3^^^WANT     d      s  PickH     c     c  
18  OBX     g            h     e      z      s     g     g
19  ORC     i            j            p      p     i     i
20  OBR     e         Acc3        PickJ      v     e     e  unique
21   \n  none         none  none   none   none  none  none
22  MSH     a            b     e      e      r     a     a
23  PID     c      ^^^WANT     d      s  PickK     c     c
24  OBR     e         Acc1        PickM      v     e     e  Not Unique
25  OBX     g            h     e             s     g
```

Here is the df:

```
{'col1': ['MSH',
  'PID',
  'OBR',
  'OBX',
  'ORC',
  '/n',
  'MSH',
  'PID',
  'OBX',
  'ORC',
  'OBR',
  'OBX',
  'OBX',
  'OBX',
  'OBX',
  '\n',
  'MSH',
  'PID',
  'OBX',
  'ORC',
  'OBR',
  '\n',
  'MSH',
  'PID',
  'OBR',
  'OBX'],
 'col2': ['a',
  'b',
  'e',
  'g',
  'i',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'g',
  'i',
  'e',
  'g',
  'i',
  'g',
  'i',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'g',
  'i',
  'e',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'e',
  'g'],
 'col3': ['b',
  'MRN1^^^WANT',
  'Acc1',
  'h',
  'j',
  'nine',
  'b',
  '^^^WANT',
  'h',
  'j',
  'Acc2',
  'h',
  'j',
  'h',
  'j',
  'none',
  'b',
  'MRN3^^^WANT',
  'h',
  'j',
  'Acc3',
  'none',
  'b',
  '^^^WANT',
  'Acc1',
  'h'],
 'col4': ['e',
  'd',
  '',
  'e',
  'p',
  'none',
  'e',
  'd',
  'e',
  '',
  '',
  'e',
  'p',
  'e',
  'p',
  'none',
  'e',
  'd',
  'e',
  '',
  '',
  'none',
  'e',
  'd',
  '',
  'e'],
 'col5': ['e',
  's',
  'PickD',
  '',
  'p',
  'none',
  'e',
  's',
  'z',
  'p',
  'PickG',
  '',
  'p',
  '',
  'p',
  'none',
  'e',
  's',
  'z',
  'p',
  'PickJ',
  'none',
  'e',
  's',
  'PickM',
  ''],
 'col6': ['r',
  'PickB',
  'v',
  's',
  'p',
  'none',
  'r',
  'PickF',
  's',
  'p',
  'v',
  's',
  'p',
  's',
  'p',
  'none',
  'r',
  'PickH',
  's',
  'p',
  'v',
  'none',
  'r',
  'PickK',
  'v',
  's'],
 'col7': ['a',
  'b',
  'e',
  '',
  'i',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'g',
  'i',
  '',
  'g',
  'i',
  'g',
  'i',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'g',
  'i',
  'e',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'e',
  'g'],
 'col8': ['a',
  'b',
  'e',
  'g',
  'i',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'g',
  'i',
  'e',
  'g',
  'i',
  '',
  'i',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'g',
  'i',
  'e',
  'none',
  'a',
  'c',
  'e',
  '']}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clearly define your requirements for unique and non-unique.  Please describe these rules in terms of the col headers and values for a row.  Asv written, your explanation is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: Okay I have tried to explain it a bit better, I hope this helps.

Comment: When you say col3 contains ACC with the same value You want to identify rows with Col3 = 'Accx' where x is a single digit integer . If col3 value startswith Acc and is unique (i.e. only 1 row having this value) then mark the row as unique, if col3 = 'Accx' and there are teo or more entries equal to 'Accx' then what?  I don't understand sections and don't follow the logic.

Comment: I am sorry it is so confusing I am trying my best to explain. So the only rows I care about are the ones starting with OBR and PID in the row starting with OBR there is a number in col3 that may be unique to that OBR or it may not be I need to see if it is Unique to that OBR. so if there is another OBR row somewhere in the df that has that same number then I need to check the PID row col3 MRN value associated with that OBR, (the PID section will always be above the OBR row). If all of the OBR rows that have the same ACC have an MRN with a number in front then forget about it. (continued)

Comment: But if one of the MRNs associated with that non-unique ACC number does not have a number in front of the ^^^WANT I want to then Append 'Not Unique' to the end of the row that starts with OBR. I hope this might help